# Как изменить исходные файлы библиотеки

Tags: android-studio

Мне нужно допилить одну библиотеку, я работаю через android studio, и использую gradle скрипт, я еще новичок и не знаю как это делается, нужно качать исходники и вливать в свой проект? Как быть тогда с названием пакета? Вообщем хотелось бы пошаговую инструкцию как это делается.

Comment: Многое зависит от того, где находятся исходники. Почти все современные библиотеки разрабатываются на github, но бывают и исключения. Уточните, какая библиотека вас интересует

Comment: Да на github'e вот https://github.com/shehabic/Droppy